# How to merge two pom.xml by dom4j

Tags: java, xml, maven

I have two pom.xml come from two similar project. I have to merge these two pom.xml into one and replace the original pom files with it.

The first pom.xml:

```xml
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>xxx</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>zzz</groupId>
            <artifactId>zzz</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>...</execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

The other one:

```xml
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>yyy</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>zzz</groupId>
            <artifactId>zzz</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>...</annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

Desired output:

```xml
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>xxx</dependency>
    <dependency>yyy</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>zzz</groupId>
            <artifactId>zzz</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>...</execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>...</annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

I've tried to code with Dom4j, it only work with "dependencies". I dont know how to merge "plugins". This is my code:

```
    Document docOfTarget = readXml(outPutFile);
    Document docOfSource = readXml(request.getSrcTemplateFile());
    Element dependenciesOfTarget = docOfTarget.getRootElement().element("dependencies");
    Element dependenciesOfSource = docOfSource.getRootElement().element("dependencies");

    List<Node> targetContents = dependenciesOfTarget.content();
    List<Node> addContents = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Node addContent : dependenciesOfSource.content()) {
        if (includeNode(targetContents, addContent)) {
            continue;
        }
        addContents.add(addContent);
    }
    targetContents.addAll(addContents);
```

```
    protected final boolean includeNode(List<Node> contents, Node comparatorNode) {
        NodeComparator nodeComparator = new NodeComparator();
        for (Node content : contents) {
            if (nodeComparator.compare(content, comparatorNode) == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

How should I do next?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not do it manually?

Comment: @JFabianMeierj, I am writing a maven project initializer like https://start.spring.io/ which my colleague require. The difference is that pom.xml come from two existed files.

Comment: The code for the project initializr exists https://github.com/spring-io/initializr. ?

Comment: @khmarbaisek, Unfortunately I can not use this, it must base on an old project.

Comment: Apart from that the merged result looks not very good. The source/target is usually for maven-compiler-plugin which should be set via properties `<maven.compiler.target>` and/or `<maven.compiler.source>` furthermore I would read the whole p[om model not on dom](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-model/apidocs/index.html)  based which is much easier and more flexible... so you can programatically get all the informations and do the handling there.. and finally write a new pom file...